# How to use $x + \frac{1}{x} = 7$ to compute $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not sure how to approach this question:

> You know that $x + \frac{1}{x} = 7$. Compute $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

I have tried adding $x + \frac{1}{x}$ to get $\frac{x^2 +1}{x}$ but can't see if this was useful or not.

I need help in getting started.

Comment: You can multiple by x, solve the equation and compute the formula

Comment: Better to just square both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notice $\left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 2$.

Answer (score 9):

Observe that
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right
)^2-2.$$
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Simple, effective and to the point. While calculating $x$ from the equation is not hard, this is much, much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. :)

Answer (score 4):

Thank you to Yiyuan Lee and awllower who really answered the question.

I am only adding this for completeness, and to remind myself of the solution.

We are given $x + \frac{1}{x} =7$ and want to use this to find $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Using the fact $$\left(x +\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 = x^2 +\frac{1}{x^2} +2$$
and rewriting this as: 
$$\left(x +\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 -2 = x^2 +\frac{1}{x^2}$$
We can substitute $x + \frac{1}{x} =7$ to get:
$$(7)^2 -2 = x^2 +\frac{1}{x^2}$$
So $$x^2 +\frac{1}{x^2} = 47$$
The same method can be used to calculate $x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}$:
$$\left(x +\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 = x^3 +\frac{1}{x^3} +3x +\frac{3}{x}$$
Noticing that $3x +\frac{3}{x}$ = $3(x+ \frac{1}{x})$, which means $3x +\frac{3}{x} = 3.(7) = 21$

Then it is possible to write:
$$\left(x +\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 -21 = x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}$$
$$(7)^3 -21 = x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}$$
$$x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3} = 343 -21$$
$$x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3} = 322$$

Comment: In fact, the same approach can be used to find $x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}$ for $4,5,6...$.

Comment: I was thinking of ways to extend the approach to show it for the nth case. Thank you again for your help and interest.

Comment: Use $(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3})=x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}+(x+\frac{1}{x})$ to find $x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}$ and generalize it to other powers.

Comment: Or, you could generalize it with a recursive general formula, perhaps through induction. I would find such a formula more useful.

Comment: @mikoyan Since it seems you are interested, I have a challenge for you: If given that $x+\frac{1}{x}= \sqrt{3}$, then find, $$x^{204}+\frac{1}{x^{204}}$$